# scrapy shell: output result to file

Tags: python, csv, scrapy, output

How can I in scrapy shell output results to a file, preferably csv?

I have a list of interesting elements in my `bpython` shell, I can make `item` of them. But how to redirect it to a file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you are in the shell, you can do whatever you want to do using Python. That includes reading/writing data from/to a file using [json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) or [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) modules, for instance.

But, since we are talking about Scrapy and csv, let's use Scrapy's [CsvItemExporter](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exporters.html#scrapy.exporters.CsvItemExporter) to get the job done:

```
from scrapy.exporters import CsvItemExporter
items = [{'one': 'data', 'two': 'more data'}, {'one': 'info', 'two': 'more info'}]
with open('data.csv', 'w') as f:
    exporter = CsvItemExporter(file=f, fields_to_export=['one', 'two'])
    exporter.start_exporting()
    for i in items:
        exporter.export_item(i)
    exporter.finish_exporting()
```

That's a stripped down version of what Scrapy does when you add the `-o` option to the `crawl` command to save the output to a file.

Answer (score -1):

Does the following answer your question?

https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html

*One of the most frequently required features when implementing scrapers is being able to store the scraped data properly and, quite often, that means generating an “export file” with the scraped data (commonly called “export feed”) to be consumed by other systems.
Scrapy provides this functionality out of the box with the Feed Exports, which allows you to generate a feed with the scraped items, using multiple serialization formats and storage backends.*

https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#topics-feed-format-csv

CSV

FEED_FORMAT: csv

Exporter used: CsvItemExporter

To specify columns to export and their order use FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS. Other feed exporters can also use this option, but it is important for CSV because unlike many other export formats CSV uses a fixed header.